# oserror python 3.5.4 on win 10 1709 when using nosetest or print

Tags: python, windows-10

Since I upgraded my win 10 version 1703 to version 1709 (Fall Update), I have a persistent problem **OSError** when using `print` or `nose` command. My log with `nose`:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_future_link_to_update_3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\sdn\work\git\pop-extrapole\env\lib\site-packages\nose\case.py", line 134, in run
    self.runTest(result)
  File "c:\users\sdn\work\git\pop-extrapole\env\lib\site-packages\nose\case.py", line 152, in runTest
    test(result)
  File "c:\program files\python35\Lib\unittest\case.py", line 653, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwds)
  File "c:\program files\python35\Lib\unittest\case.py", line 621, in run
    result.addSuccess(self)
  File "c:\users\sdn\work\git\pop-extrapole\env\lib\site-packages\nose\proxy.py", line 165, in addSuccess
    self.result.addSuccess(self.test)
  File "c:\program files\python35\Lib\unittest\runner.py", line 64, in addSuccess
    self.stream.flush()
OSError: raw write() returned invalid length 2 (should have been between 0 and 1)
```

I can pass this problem by commenting `self.stream.flush()` but it's not a solution:

```
def addSuccess(self, test):
    super(TextTestResult, self).addSuccess(test)
    if self.showAll:
       self.stream.writeln("ok")
    elif self.dots:
       self.stream.write('.')
       # self.stream.flush()
```

Other log when using `print`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files\python35\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "c:\program files\python35\Lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 47, in starmapstar
    return list(itertools.starmap(args[0], args[1]))
  File "C:\Users\SDN\Work\git\pop-extrapole\extrapolation\extrapole.py", line 1463, in popcorn_process
    print(lk)
OSError: raw write() returned invalid length 46 (should have been between 0 and 23)
```

Does anyone have an idea about that?

Thanks,
Uwevil

Comment: by any chance are you using selenium or UI testing using nose ? if it is so then it is long known issue refer: https://github.com/nameko/nameko/issues/368

Comment: Hello, I don't use selenium and nay other UI testing, I only use nose to run my unit tests. This problem can persist when I use `print` also. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the bash of "Git for Windows"?

If you use, Try to add the administrator rights to the property settings of  `\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe`and `\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\bash.exe`.

I could solved by it. But I think that this is not best solution.

And the other solution is the using PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I use also "Git for Windows". but after changing the admin rights of `git-bash.exe` and `bash.exe`, the problem was not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this problem seem to be handled by upgrade python 3.5.4 to python 3.6.4 according to this thread: https://bugs.python.org/issue32245